# How use domain integrity constraint in sql server new version and Assertion constraint

Tags: sql, database

How use domain constraint in sql server new version because when write query with domain key word then show error on domain key word.Because i think my sql server version is 2019.

Comment: Show your code and explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Create domain name As char (1) check (value in ('F', 'M'));